# jscrollpane unfunctional in firefox, functional in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, jscrollpane

I'm using jScrollpane to showcase a mix of images and a div horizontally. I managed to get it to work on chrome, but I think firefox is not picking the CSS to keep images no-wrap, and doesn't scroll horizontally.

You can see it in action here --

http://dentasignclients.com/opo2/single-portfolio.php

The relevant CSS is the following :

```
.scroll-pane{
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    overflow: scroll;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.scroll-pane ul{
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
}

.scroll-pane ul li{
    float:left;
}

.scroll-pane ul li img{
    height:420px;
}

.info{
    display: block;
    clear: left;
    width:300px;
    height:420px;
    background-color:gray;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:normal;
}
```

What are your thoughts on making this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of floating the `li`'s left, use `display:inline-block`

```
.scroll-pane ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
}
```

Comment: Aand that did the trick! Thanks, I'm going to dedicate a day to really understanding positioning in CSS.